# how to export query to Excel without truncating Memos to 255 chars?

Tags: excel, ms-access

Using Access 2010.  I have a query with several Memo fields in it that I would like to export to an Excel sheet.  Every method I have tried so far has truncated the Memo fields:

- Export Wizard
- Right-clicking on the query and choosing Export
- Exporting to CSV
- `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`
- Copy/pasting the data into open Excel sheet

How can I get all the Memo data in my export, or at least the full 32767 characters that an Excel cell can display?

Comment: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/avoiding-data-cut-off-in-excel/ (Have you tried all of the methods on that page?)

Comment: See [Truncation of Memo fields](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaam's suggestion was very helpful.  I ended up doing this the following way:

1. Select query into table.
2. In design view, change relevant Text fields to Memo fields, because the `SELECT INTO` automatically set them as Text.
3. Delete all rows from table.
4. Add rows from query using `INSERT INTO`.
5. Import table contents into Excel range using `Range.CopyFromRecordset`.  I had to do this from the table instead of directly from the query because I had UDFs in my query.

Answer (score 5):

Export into excel with option "Export data with formating and layout" set to YES. If this checkbox is not set to yes, access truncate texts to first 255 characters.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsAbB.jpg)

Comment: Thank you, I was having the same issue and this was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

We are using older version of MS Access and XL and cannot upgrade so "export data with formatting and layout" is not available. Doing Copy > Paste Special > Text worked for our use case and didn't have to rework queries etc. but doesn't work if answer set is more than a few thousand rows.